# How to set custom font in ATOM-editor on Mac?

Tags: macos, fonts, atom-editor

Have googled around and still not been able to find an answer that allowed me to change the atom editor font the way I want.

## What I did...

I have merged 3 fonts together via TransType 4 into one font I call Inconsolata Operator. I have installed it on my mac:

[image]

This allows me to do this in the Notes App with just one font (or font-family?):

[image]

## What I want...

How do I get to use this font in ATOM editor?

I wish to keep the theme (currently using cobalt2) and only change the font.

---

## What I achieved...

After `tadek` answer I finally got the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing this via `settings->editor->Font Familly` ?

Comment: Tried `InconsolataOperator` and `Inconsolata Operator`

Comment: Found the issue! I forgot to uninstall a package called `Fonts`. Did that and now it works! Thanks